# ValueError: Length of values (586) does not match length of index (521)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames that I am comparing two columns `df_luad['Tumor_Sample_Barcode']` and `df_tmb['Patient ID']` of them, if the two columns values from two dataframes are equal, then it adds a column from the second dataframe `df_tmb['TMB (nonsynonymous)']`to a new third dataframe `df1` column `df1['tmb_value']`.

```
df1['tmb_value'] = np.where(df_luad['Tumor_Sample_Barcode'].eq(df_tmb['Patient ID']), 'True' , df_tmb['TMB (nonsynonymous)'])
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
*** ValueError: Length of values (586) does not match length of index (521)
```

which is related to the row numbers. `df_luad` has 521 rows and `df_tmb` has 586 rows. how to add the values of `df_tmb['TMB (nonsynonymous)']` only for the matching rows (records) in `df_luad`?

the following is `df_tmb` data
[image]

and this is `df_luad`:

[image]

Comment: Which column are you using to do the matching? If the two DataFrames have different lengths then you would need a common column to do the matching or alignment. If not, what criteria should pandas use to know which row of `df_luad['Tumor_Sample_Barcode']` to compare with `df_tmb['Patient ID']`?

Comment: @andrea yes the value of these two columns are being compared. if it finds the rows that the value of `df_luad['Tumor_Sample_Barcode']==df_tmb['Patient ID']`, then it adds the values of `df_tmb['TMB (nonsynonymous)']` to the new column of `df1['tmb_value']` which is `df1=df_luad` previously.

Comment: @andrea I edited the question for clarity

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you may wish to use panda's [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) method. It would look something like this

```py
df1 = df_luad.merge(
    df_tmb, left_on='Tumor_Sample_Barcode', right_on='Patient ID', how='left'
)
```

In this case all rows of `df_tmb` where the value of `'Patient ID'` is also present in the `'Tumor_Sample_Barcode'` column of `df_luad` should be merged. The merge will include all columns of `df_tmb` including `'TMB (nonsynonymous)'`. If there are other columns you do not want then you will have to remove them manually.

If this doesn't produce the required effect then please post a full reproducible example including expected output so we can better understand your question.